# Steps before field deletion

Tags: apex

I am going through the process to delete a field in SFDC.

Is there any way to check all custom settings and labels to see if the field api name is held in text within either of those?

I am trying to avoid manually checking each one.

Thanks

Edit: maybe this is unclear. I want to check if a specific string is held in custom settings or custom labels

Comment: While you will not able to delete a field if its referenced in say apex classes, but if you would like to verify the existence of this field, there is no way to do this out of the box. A possible way could be to export your metadata for the custom settings and labels and then look for the existence of this field api across the workspace.

Comment: let me rephrase, I want to check if a string is held in any of the custom settings or custom labels

Comment: Sure, the approach still remains the same. Like you export the metadata (or data in case of custom setting) and look for whatever string literal you want to look for within those set.

Comment: There is no shortcut. You are going to have to manually inspect.

Comment: For Custom Settings, you could write Apex to walk the global describe, identify Custom Settings types, pull the records for each type, and inspect their fields for the API name. Doing this *right*, though, would probably be more time-consuming than manual inspection unless you have an enormous quantity of custom settings that refer to API names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get error message if you try to delete a field, if it's referenced in say apex classes, but there is **no out of the box** way that you will be able to verify existence of a field's reference specifically in your case as with Custom Settings or Custom Labels. You will still need to verify it manually but using some approaches (as below) you can save significant effort around going things individually.

For Custom Label - Let's say you want to refer the field's existence in Custom Label, the best way to do this will be to export the metadata information of possibly all Custom Labels in your sandbox and then using editor tools, you can search for existence of the string literal you are searching for.

For Custom Settings - You can extract the data hosted in the Custom Settings and once you have the data extract, you can perform the search in the extracted file.